# CakePHP 3 : restrict access to whole controller without login

Tags: cakephp, authorization, cakephp-3.2

I have a controller `UserAddresses` where only logged in users are allowed to add/edit/delete their addresses.

But since `AppController.php` contains

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
  $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display', 'home']);
}
```

`www.website.com/user-addresses/` is accessible even without login.
I want to restrict all actions of `userAddresses` controller.

How can I do it from controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I do it from controller.

For example by overriding `beforeFilter()` in your `UserAddressesController` class, and removing possible entries from the list of allowed actions.

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->deny(); // deny all actions
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Authentication > Making Actions Require Authorization](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#making-actions-require-authorization)**
- **[API > \Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent::deny()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Controller.Component.AuthComponent.html#_deny)**